# Is it possible to condense this code?

Tags: javascript

I have three functions, each assigned to an anchor tag which gets called `onclick`.

Is there a way to condense this code? It seems redundant to have three function calls which do the same thing except the value is different for each.

```
var winnings = 0;

function add20() {
    winnings += 20;
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}

function add40() {
    winnings += 40;
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}

function add60() {
    winnings += 60;
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}
```

Comment: Sure: `function addWinnings(amount) { winnings += amount; .. }` Generally, one should keep *data* out of identifiers - and the amount 20/40/60 (which is data) should likely come from another source (e.g. the 'bet' and subsequent 'payout').

Answer (score 5):

You could just create one function, like this:

```
function add(x) { 
    winnings += x; 
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}
```

But if you *need* three different versions, you could always do this:

```
var winnings = 0;
function addX(x) { 
    return function() { 
        winnings += x; 
        document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
    }
}

var add20 = addX(20);
var add40 = addX(40);
var add60 = addX(60);
```

Or even more simply:

```
function add(x) { 
    winnings += x; 
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}
function add20() { add(20); }
function add40() { add(40); }
function add60() { add(60); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function add(val) {
    winnings += val;
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML = winnings;
}
```

Calling it with

```
add(20); // Adding 20
```

Or

```
add(40); // Adding 40
```

Etc

Comment: Worked! Just what I needed. Looking at the solution now, it's pretty simple but I am fairly new to programming so I guess I can give myself some slack.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass parameters like this

```
function addWinnings(amount) {
    winnings+=amount;
    document.getElementById("winnings").innerHTML=winnings;
}
```

Comment: better move getElementById out of procedure. From perfomance perspective, imagine,  having 10 calls of addWinnings will raise 10 DOM updates. not good.

Comment: @EugeneP Sorry, what? How else could he do it

Comment: Once again: Imagine case I do need to call procedure 10 times in a row. It will mean DOM get update 10 times.  If you move getElementById away from procedure. update will be done 1 time. It's just perfomance note, applicable for all provided solutions posted here

Comment: But that's what the OP wants to do